# Telerik report designer - substraction of sub total from 2 tables

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I have attached the Telerik report design SS, as I have used 2 tables Lease and credit, and from this, I want to subtract the subtotal between **lease** and **credit** and show it in the **grand total**. But I am stuck in that, I have tried lots of solutions but I am not achieving my result.
Please share your suggestions, it will be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Want to substration of sub total from Lease - Credit]